# StackOverflow error when casting to a superclass

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I've found the following code on the internet.

```
 class A {
        public void perform_work() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }
class B extends A {
    public void perform_work() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public void perform_work() {
        ((A) this).perform_work(); // Line 163
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        c.perform_work();
    }
}
```

This code compiles cleanly, but It gives me an error when running it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
    at com.hamzablm.C.perform_work(Main.java:163)
```

........................................... more error like that

I was expecting that line 163 (specified in the above code) would call `perfom_work()` defined in class A. Why this error was generated? And how to solve it?

Comment: Unrelated: for your own code, adhere to Java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase in Java, always.

Comment: This isn't my code. Just a copy paste from the web.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want `perfom_work` in `C` to execute `perfom_work` in `A` you need to change it to:

```
public void perform_work() {
    super.perform_work();
}
```

And do the same change in `B`

As it is currently written it is calling itself recursively, so it never stops.

Comment: Oh, I see it's recursive because `this` is pointing to a class instance of `C`.

Comment: @hamzabelmellouki, that's correct. With `super` you're basically saying: "hey, call the  `perform_work` method defined in my _ancestor_".

Answer (score 1):

In `C` in `perform_work` `this` is typecast from `C` to `A` so `perform_work` in `A` is called instead but this method is overridden in `C` so it goes back there where once again a typecast is done and it all happens again until you get a `StackOverflowError`

As mentioned in the other answer you need to use `super` to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written in method perform_work() in class C is essentially equivalent to this:

```
public void perform_work() {
    A someA = this;
    someA.perform_work();
}
```

which as you will probably know does not change the type of the object referenced by the variable someA. It is still an object of type C and calling the perform_work() method on a reference to it will call the implementation from class C.

Just imagine the following scenario:

```
public static void perform_more_work(A someA) {
    someA.perform_work();
}

public void perform_work() {
    perform_more_work(this);
}
```

It should be obvious which method will be called by the above code.

Comment: Sure, I understood. This is all done by polymorphism and the actual object the reference variable is pointing to.